# URI scheme to locate a resource in a maven dependency?

Tags: maven, dependencies, rfc3986

I need a URI to locate a resource in a maven dependency. For example, if I declare a dependency :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>top.marchand.xml</groupId>
  <artifactId>xslLibrary</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I want to access ot `/path/to/file.xsl` that is inside xslLibrary. For sure, I can access via classpath resource loading, but I **need** a URI to point this resource.

Does a URI scheme (according to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1) ) has already been registered at IETF for such things ?

I would like to register something like :

```
dependency://groupId+artifactId$version/path/to/file.xsl
```

Thanks in advance,
Christophe

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented such a protocol, based on XML catalogs. Available as a maven plugin here : https://github.com/cmarchand/maven-catalogBuilder-plugin/wiki

Also implemented as a Protocol Handler in oXygen XML Developer : https://github.com/cmarchand/oxygen-maven-project-support

Comment: Don't answer with just links please. explain what is your implementation and how to use it in your answer.